# Regression model/ non-linear regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, arima, non-linear-regression

The dataset has a timestamp and the water flow values, Now I want to model the data such that if any abnormal value(sudden spike or very low value) comes in it should send a notification that something is wrong. I have tried the ARIMA model to train the data since it was time series but it doesnt produce relevant results which means I am doing something wrong. So please guide me. Thanks. The link to the dataset is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cFHSVpY0XBxsEayl2k1cK4_qWZ4PvDBd

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
features = [col for col in x2.columns if 'day' in col]
X = x2['median'].reshape(-1,1)
y = x2['time']
# create linear regression object 
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
# train the model using the training sets 
reg.fit(X, y) 
# regression coefficients 
print('Coefficients: \n', reg.coef_)
```

I have tried using the median of all the water flow value for each time interval as the target variable but it produces negative variance score as well.

The expected result should be a value of water flow at the given time which tells if it is in a normal range or not.

Comment: What do you mean by water flow being normal?

Comment: So have you used `reg.predict()` and used a confidence interval to check for normal values?

Comment: @AbhineetGupta water flow being normal means it is between a range. the values specified here are the normal ranges. If it spikes or gets too low then it is considered as an abnormal behavior

Answer (score 0):

Since this problem seems to be a single feature problem, I recommend starting with plotting median water flow with respect to time. The shape of the plot will tell you how best to model the problem.

Comment: thanks for the response. I have tried the median value but I am still not sure what model to use. I tried using the ARIMA model since it was a time series data but the results seem off and I'm pretty sure I am doing something wrong. I am sharing the link to the dataset if you want to have a look at it. Thanks.